# gmap3 clear marker not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help resolve this issue.

the clear marker is working in FF & IE but not chrome?

```
    function addMarker(lati, longi, id, name) {
    $('#dispatcher').gmap3(
      { action: 'addMarker',
        lat: lati,
        lng: longi,
        tag: name,
        options: {
            icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/pin.png')
        }
      }
      );
}

function clearMarker(name) {
        $('#dispatcher').gmap3({ 
            action: 'clear',
            tag: name
        });

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'clearMarker'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleared the cache in chrome - fixed.. sorry